# Valores separados por coma para filtrar - PHP - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, filtro

Estoy tratando de separar valores con coma dentro de un campo personalizado para que el plugin que utilizo de filtros pueda separarlos.

El campo personalizado se llama `'sub_ubicacion_norte'`.

Los valores son por ejemplo en un post: "San Isidro, Vicente Lopez, Pilar".

Ahora en el filtro me aparece "San Isidro, Vicente Lopez, Pilar" como una sola opción y quiero que sean tres en este caso.

El código que estoy incrustando en `functions.php` es:

```
function my_acf_update_norte1( $value, $post_id, $field) {

$field1 = get_field('sub_ubicacion_norte');
var_dump($field1);


$norte1 = substr($field1, 0,1);

var_dump($norte1);

return $norte1;
}
add_filter('acf/update_value/name=sub_ubicacion_norte','my_acf_update_norte1', 10, 3);


function my_acf_update_norte2( $value, $post_id, $field) {

$field2 = get_field('sub_ubicacion_norte');
var_dump($field2);


$norte2 = substr($field2, 1,2);

var_dump($norte2);

return $norte2;
}
add_filter('acf/update_value/name=sub_ubicacion_norte','my_acf_update_norte2', 10, 3);
```

Comment: No entiendo bien lo que hace tu código, pero a simple vista parece un código *poco práctico*  y quizá algo precario, es lo que uno piensa desde que ve que se declaran variables como `$field1, $field2, $fieldN...`. ¿Por qué no escribir un código flexible, que reciba a `$field` sin importar cuántos valores tenga, los divida según el separador y cree tantos campos como valores haya, sean estos 3, ó 10 ó 500? En PHP, para crear un array a partir de un separador la función que se usa es [**`explode`**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php), ¿no será lo que necesitas, en vez de `substr`?

Comment: ¿Por qué no escribir un código flexible, que reciba a $field sin importar cuántos valores tenga, los divida según el separador y cree tantos campos como valores haya, sean estos 3, ó 10 ó 500? Es exactamente lo que quiero hacer, pero no se como, podras ayudarme? en donde identifico el campo personalizado para que se nombre como unico para esos 3 o 10? Muchas gracias por ayuda!

Comment: Si `$field` es una cadena separada por comas parecida a `San Isidro, Vicente Lopez, Pilar` entonces puedes crear un array que individualice cada valor usando `explode`  de este modo: `$arrFields=explode(", ",$field);` y luego para obtener cada valor por separado sin importar cuántos sean, abres un bucle para leer el array: `foreach ($arrFields as $v){echo $v;}`  Dentro del bucle, tendrás en la variable `$v` los valores: `San Isidro`, `Vicente López` y `Pilar` por separado. Lo demás es cuestión de presentarlos o tratarlos para tus requerimientos.

Comment: hola! Aplique lo que me indicas, lo que veo es que me eliminan las comas pero no me lo separa por campos, hay algo que estoy haciendo mal?                         
** $value=get_field('sub_ubicacion_norte');
$arrFields= explode(", ",$value);
if( $value){
    foreach($arrFields as $v){
        echo $v;
    };
}**Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Encontre la respuesta en esta publicacion por si alguien lo necesita.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31773745/meta-query-filter-by-tag-wordpress

Muchas gracias a todos!